# KL divergence of Binomial Distributions with different 'n'

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, information-theory

If I have two binomial random variables, say $X\sim Bin(n, p)$ and $Y \sim Bin(m, q)$, can I calculate their KL divergence? My initial thought is no, because the random variables have different supports (i.e. $0\leq X \leq n$ and $0\leq Y \leq m$), but I wondered if there was a way around this? Thanks

Comment: The Kullback–Leibler divergence is generally asymmetric so $D_\text{KL}(P \parallel Q) = \sum\limits_{x\in\mathcal{X}} P(x) \log\left(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right) \not = D_\text{KL}(Q \parallel P)$.  The summands are taken to be $0$ when $P(x)=0$ so you can do the calculation so long as $P$ corresponds to the random variable with smaller $n$ or $m$ and $Q$ to the one with the larger, but not the other way round.